# How to get a Max count for a category?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables that hold Empolyee and Office data:

- `EMPLOYEE (EmpID, Role, OfficeNumber)`
- `OFFICE (OfficeNumber, Region, Manager)`

Employees can be registered under multiple offices with different roles.

For example below the Employee is registered in 2 offices (20 & 50) but has more entries in office 20 so we want to select that as his "Home" Office

```
EmpID | Role | Region | Manager | OfficeNumber

15    | 1    | East   | James   | 20
15    | 4    | East   | James   | 20
15    | 5    | East   | James   | 20
15    | 1    | West   | George  | 50
15    | 5    | West   | George  | 50
```

Basically I want to get a count for which office the employee is registered under the most for that region, then return the manager for that office..

So for the above employee the result for their "Home Office" would be:

```
EmpID | Region | Manager | OfficeNumber
15    | East   | James   | 20
```

This is the SQL that I have put together.

```
SELECT 
    EmpID, Manager, Region,
    Count (OfficeNumber),
    Row_Number(Partition by EmpID ORDER by   
    Count(OfficeNumber) Desc)
FROM 
Employees e
JOIN 
Offices o ON e.OfficeNumber = o.OfficeNumber
```

Not sure if I'm using the Row_Number function properly or whether there would be a better approach?

Comment: What happens if empid 15 had exactly 3 records for officenumber 20 and 50? What will be the home office of empid 15?

Comment: I didnt think of that situation :/ Do you know if a case statement would work?

Comment: `CASE` statement will help when the requirement is known. My question tries to find what should be displayed in the described situation. Based on your needs we can determine what statements are needed. Also, you had tagged the question with MySQL. The question was edited with SQL Server tag. Which database are you really using - MySQL or SQL Server or something else?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2014. I would need the Employee's MOST locations to be Labeled as " Home" and the cases which the employee has equal office locations to be labeled as " No Match" in order to be resolved manually.  Would the case statement be included within the main subquery or use a temp table? also how would the case look like using the CTE @pcofre provided below?

Answer (score 0):

Two CTEs can do the job. The 1st one creates the counts per Employee/Office and the second one gets the Main Office for each Employee. Hope it works 4 u

```
with CountCte as (
SELECT *,count(*) over (partition by [EmpID],[OfficeNumber]) OfficeCount
FROM 
Employees e
JOIN 
Offices o ON e.OfficeNumber = o.OfficeNumber),
MainCte as (
select  *,row_number() over (partition by [EmpID] order by OfficeCount desc) r
from    CountCte)
select  EmpID
        ,Region
        ,Manager
        ,OfficeNUmber
from    MainCte
where r = 1
```